# How do I download a linked pdf file from its url using python?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, python-s3fs

I have multiple URL's like 'https://static.nseindia.com/s3fs-public/2022-09/ind_prs01092022.pdf' and I want to loop through an array of these and download them to a local folder.
I saw that I may need to use s3fs, but I am unsure what the bucket name should be. ([download file using s3fs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017653/download-file-using-s3fs))

Comment: Do you know the URLs anyhow? If so, you can just open a [`requests.Session`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and `get` the files one by one in a loop or in parallel using [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html).

Comment: @StSav012 I tried that. Just times out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the web server doesn't respond unless a user agent is among the request headers. The behavior is fairly common.

```py
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get('https://static.nseindia.com/s3fs-public/2022-09/ind_prs01092022.pdf',
           headers={'User-Agent': 'Python'}  # or any non-empty string
    )
```